# How to change type in all code

Tags: c#, types, uwp

I'm studing the UWP coding in C#. I've done a little Grid with some rectangles:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
```

I've done it in many methods of class. I would create a generic type (for example as class or a variable) to fast change all Rectangles in Ellipse (for example), not at runtime. I mean something like:

```
Type ShapeType = typeof(Rectangle);
```

and create:

```
ShapeType figure = new ShapeType(); ...
```

but tomorrow be able to change

```
Type ShapeType = typeof(Rectangle);
```

in

```
Type ShapeType = typeof(Ellipse);
```

and change all the shapes in my code. Is this possible? How can I create a class "Rectangle-like" or "Ellipse-like" ?

Thank you

Marked as duplicate of: 
"*Get a new object instance from a Type*
One may not always know the Type of an object at compile-time, but may need to create an instance of the Type. How do you get a new object instance from a Type?"

Where I've written that I want create an object at runtime? Or also only that i want create an object? 
My question is about "How to change (from code) easily the type defined in many line of code creating a generic type?"

Comment: You're looking for generics.

Comment: @SLaks have a good suggestion.But I have a suggestion that you can try use ctrl + H.

Comment: Your question is really unclear, could you explain a bit more? From what I've gathered you want to replace *the code* all at once? That's a question about your editor, really.

Comment: As @lindexi said, _Find and Replace_ is your friend.  As what you said, you are not to do in run-time, which means all codes are just plain text, nothing related to programming.  Or you talking inheritance?

Comment: Install ReSharper tool and it'll help you to refactor your code easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to have a factory method that would create a new instance of the element you decide to use.

It could look like this:

```
private Shape CreateShape() => new Rectangle();
```

Because all `Shape` elements in UWP have `Shape` as a base class, you can use it as the return type of your method and as a "base" type in all places you use the shape.

You can now replace all the lines, where you created instances of `Rectangle` with the following:

```
var shape = CreateShape();
```

If you later decide that you want to change the type to `Ellipse`, you just change the code in one place - in the `CreateShape` method:

```
private Shape CreateShape() => new Ellipse();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, nice suggestion!